# Query schtasks using Powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, scheduled-task

On a Windows7 machine I am trying I can run a query to view all the scheduled tasks using schtasks.exe

This is fine but I would also like to filter the result set using something like

```
schtasks /query | where { $_.TaskName -eq "myTask" }
```

The problem is I don't this schtasks returns a properly formatted list for the where function to work.

I've also tried:

```
schtasks /query /FO LIST
schtasks /query | format-list | where ....
```

those don't work either.

What would be the best way to query the schtasks on a local computer using Win7 and be able to filter them

Comment: What's with the backslashes in there? I'm fairly sure that's not what `schtasks` expects there, but rather a forward slash.

Comment: ha! you're right. I've corrected it above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to use schtasks, which will leave you parsing text.  This is almost always error prone, and definitely more difficult than it is to take the output of a command.

There happens to be a TaskScheduler module in the [PowerShellPack](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/).  Once you install the PowerShell pack,  to get all of the scheduled tasks, use:

```
Import-Module TaskScheduler
Get-ScheduledTask -Recurse
```

Since these are real objects, to find a task of a particular name, you can use:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -Recurse |  Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Task*"}
```

In general, you will find that the PowerShell community has taken a lot of harder to use command lines, like schtasks, and turned them into easy-to-use cmdlets, like Get-ScheduledTask.

See Also:

[Sending Automated Emails using the TaskScheduler Module](https://web.archive.org/web/20151211233541/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powershell/archive/2009/10/30/sending-automated-emails-with-send-mailmessage-convertto-html-and-the-powershellpack-s-taskscheduler-module.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: This works great if you're using Win2k8 boxes (or vista/W7).  Unfortunately, it doesn't work with W2k3 servers (which are still very common in my environment).

Comment: @MikeShepard If you want the new toys, you have to stop using 11 year old operating systems.

Comment: That's the story of my career.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a blog post](http://powershellstation.com/2009/09/10/getting-scheduled-tasks-in-powershell/) I wrote about doing this.  Essentially, I took the output of the /FO LIST /V, wrote that to a file, and imported it back in as objects using import-csv

Comment: You're on the right track but writing to a temporary file is unnecessary here: `schtasks /query /fo csv /v|convertfrom-csv` works just fine

Comment: this is neat but still not easily queryable

Comment: Johannes:  you're right, but I really (really) dislike properties that have embedded spaces/colons/slashes.
jdiaz:  What's not queryable?  The script I posted and Johannes' revision both return native powershell objects with properties.  They should be just as queryable as any other powershell entities.

Comment: Truly - they are queryable...`schtasks /query /fo csv /v /s "myserver" | convertfrom-csv | Select TaskName, "Last Run Time", Author | ? {$_.Author -notmatch "microsoft|N/A|Author"}` will provide you with all the custom scheduled tasks you have.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need to do it in powershell then the following will work

schtasks /query | findstr /i "mytask"

ps version
schtasks /query | ?{$_ -like 'mytask'}

Comment: any full source code sample for create, query and delete tasks using PS ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
schtasks /query /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-CSV | Where { $_.TaskName -eq "myTask" }
```

The trick is in converting output to CSV first, and then back to a powershell object.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it.

Commandline for what you want
schtasks /query /s %computername%|FIND /I "%name_of_task%"

example
schtasks /query /s server01|FIND /I "schedule"

Answer (score -2):

The best options is from Alex because you dont need library and you will convert the string's answers from schtasks in Powershell object.